# Check if ALT key is pressed on bare-metal BIOS PC

Tags: assembly, x86, bootloader, bios

I'm struggling with checking if <kbd>Alt</kbd> key is pressed in linux bootloader

```
int 0x16
mov ah, 0x0e
int 0x10
```

Above code prints ascii characters just fine, but how do I check for <kbd>Alt</kbd> key?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You test bit 3 of 0040h:0017h.

http://www.ousob.com/ng/bios/ng559a.php

Something like this (in AT/T syntax):

```
mov    $0x40,%ax
mov    %ax,%es
testb  $8,%es:0x17
jz     noAltKey
.... ;; Alt pressed
noAltKey:
```

According to `objdump -d -M intel`, that's how it looks in Intel syntax:

```
0:   66 b8 40 00             mov    ax,0x40
4:   8e c0                   mov    es,eax
6:   26 f6 04 25 17 00 00    test   BYTE PTR es:0x17,0x8
d:   00 08
```

UPD: The following should work for NASM:

```
mov    ax,0x40
mov    es,eax
test   [es:0x17],byte 0x8
jz     noAltKey
.... ;; Alt pressed
noAltKey:
```

Comment: Can you please provide an example?

Comment: Shame, i can't compile this using nasm. Thank you though!